# How do I change the font type of a table? LATEX

Tags: tables

I want to make the font type of a table to be the same that I am using in the text, how do I do that? How do I change the font in a table?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please tell us which document class you employ, which text font(s) you use, and which font(s) you would like to use for table-related material.

Comment: the document class that I am using is 'book' and the font that I'm using is the 'default' and I'd like to use the \sf font in the table. Thank you for your quick reply

Comment: And which part of the `table` environment should be typeset using the sans-serif font: The table header (also called the caption), the tabular material, the footnotes, or all of the above?

Comment: I want to set this font in the tabular material

Comment: `\begin{table}\sffamily\begin{tabular} ...\end{tabular}\end{table}` ? probably global setting in document preamble for all tables?

Comment: So, the table's caption should *not* be in sans-serif?

Answer (score 7):

if you have only one table, the simplest way is

```
\begin{table}
\sffamily
\begin{tabular} ...

\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

otherwise put in preamble

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{table}{\sffamily}
```

note, this change font family only im tabular material. in caption is defined by caption set up.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a solution in case you want *everything* in the `table`, *including* the `\caption`, to be typeset using the sans-serif font: Simply insert the following instructions in the preamble:

```
\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{table}%
  {\renewcommand\familydefault\sfdefault
   \@float{table}}
  {\end@float}
\makeatother
```

A full working example:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum} % for filler text

\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{table}%
  {\renewcommand\familydefault\sfdefault
   \@float{table}}
  {\end@float}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\lipsum*[1]

\begin{table}[h!]
\caption{Hello World}
\begin{tabular}{@{}p{\textwidth}@{}}
\hline
\lipsum*[2]\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\lipsum*[3]
\end{document}
```

Comment: nice solution, (+1), however I would rather use my suggestion with `\captionsetup[table]{font=sf}` :)

Comment: @Zarko - I wanted to present a solution that doesn't depend on any specific packages (e.g., `caption`) being loaded as well. :-) However, if the caption is *not* supposed to use the sans-serif font face, then my answer won't be what the OP needs...

Answer (score 2):

I found the following solution with the [floatrow package](http://mirror.koddos.net/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/floatrow/floatrow.pdf) to work well with KOMA classes. It allows you to change the font for all of your tables:

```
\usepackage{floatrow}
floatsetup[table]{font=sf}
```

Simply add this to your preamble.
You can also combine this with other configurations, for example, to reduce the fontsize of tables:

```
floatsetup[table]{font={footnotesize,sf}}
```